# Failing to view picamera on Raspberry Pi 3 when running headless

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, headless, picamera

I am trying to run my Raspberry Pi 3B+ headless. I need to use a picamera, but it is not showing anything while running headless.

I know that the reason for this behavior is that the RPi doesn't create a virtual screen if no monitor is plugged in before booting.

-I use legacy camera setting.
-I use TeamViewer for the remote access. I don't use VNC, as I will not be able to check the IP address of the raspberry in this specific use case. (The Raspberry Pi will be accessed in another country out of reach).
-Setting up a minitor at the RPi's location is not a possibility.
-RPi os: Bullseye

Most guides, I have seen on the internet, require the IP address of RPi, so I have not found anything yet that can solve it with TeamViewer.

I was once told that I could insert an HDMI to VGA adapter to the RPi as it would inform the RPi that there is a monitor present, but I have not found anything that supports this statement.

Is there any work-around or other ways to make the picamera display headlessly?

Thanks a lot in advance!